# How can I determine the volume name of CD/DVD in bash?

Tags: macos, bash

I'm trying to figure out how to get a bash script to automatically determine the path to a CD/DVD in order to process it. Running a Mac (10.7.4) the disk shows up at:

```
/Volumes/[Volume_name]
```

Since the volume name changes depending on the disk, I'm having to input that part manually. The operating system obviously knows it's a CD/DVD because of the way the controls work. Is it possible for bash to use whatever the OS uses to determine there is a CD/DVD and provide the path to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use `drutil`.

`drutil` uses the DiscRecording framework to interact with attached burning devices.

```
#!/bin/bash
id=$(drutil status |grep -m1 -o '/dev/disk[0-9]*')
if [ -z "$id" ]; then
    echo "No Media Inserted" 
else 
    df | grep "$id" |grep -o /Volumes.*
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a UNIX block device name, *diskutil info*'s output is easier to parse than *mount*'s. For instance, this

```
function get_disk_mountpoint () {
    diskutil info $1 | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /^   Mount Point: +(.*)/';
}
```

works. Trouble is, OS X also dynamically assigns */dev/disk?* devices to removable media, so you still need something like

```
function get_optical_mountpoints () {
    for i in $(diskutil list | egrep ^/); do
        if diskutil info $i | egrep -q '^   Optical Drive Type:' ; then
            get_disk_mountpoint $i
        fi
    done
}
```

to list the mount points for optical drives specifically.

Comment: I can get that to show me the mount (e.g. /dev/disk2), but `diskutil info` but there is no "Mount Point" to look for in the output. I'm sure it's the correct drive because it reports "Optical Media Type:       DVD-R". There is a "Volume Name:", but it's value is "Not applicable (no file system)". No where in the output of diskutil do I see the name of the disk that is displaying in the finder.

Comment: You need to combine Jason's answer with Martin, or use jackjr300's, which follows the same idea.  First, get the device name (with either `diskutil info` or `drutil`), then use the device name to find the volume name.

Answer (score 0):

If a disc is mounted you can use `mount` to view where it's mounted.

Comment: This returns something like `/dev/disk2s2 on /Volumes/[Volume_name] (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, read-only, noowners)`, but I don't see how to make the determination that a specific mount is a CD/DVD.

Answer (score 0):

Putting together the pieces from above, I think this will do what you want:

```
get_cd_volume() { 
  local rc=1
  for disk in $(diskutil list | grep ^/); do 
    if diskutil info "$disk" | grep -q Optical; then
      df | sed -ne  "s,^$disk.*\(/Volumes.*\)$,\1,p"
      rc=0 
    fi
  done
  if (( rc )); then
    echo >&2 "No volume mounted."
  fi
  return $rc
}
```

Comment: This works to show the output. The trick is that if you add an "else" statement, it triggers once for every volume that's not an optical drive. It looks like the code @jackjr300 wrote doesn't have that issue.

Comment: well, sure, the if is inside a for loop. lots of ways to handle the case where nothing is mounted, but producing no output seems reasonable.   Would be better if it also set the return status appropriately.. I edited it to do so, and also display a message in that case, just to demonstrate.  Glad jackjr300's answer works for you.